# Algorithm used in compare command of Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I used Imagemagick in my project. I implemented a sub-image detection system using the compare command of ImageMagick. It is working well giving fine results. By reading articles i got to know that ImageMagick  compares pixels of small image at every possible position within the pixels of larger image.And also i got to know ImageMagick detects rotated images and scaled images using Fuzzy factor.Though i have an rough idea about how the algorithm behave i couldn't find any article related to the algorithms of ImageMagick. Any idea about how this algorithm of compare command actually works?

Comment: The fuzz factor only affects the differences in color that will be considered the same by the metric. It will not permit scale or rotation matching.

Answer (score 3):

AT my job I'm  currently working on a tool which does some sophisticated optimizations on PDF pages when they're too heavy (too much vectors etc), but sometimes whites out rectangular parts of the image due to the drawing order of PDF objects.

I decided to use the compare tool of ImageMagick v6 (retrocompatibility issues forbid v7 for the moment) to check the page rendering after treatment against original rendering and detect when there have been accidents.

I have tested the available -metrics parameters on pages where the rendering was nearly identical to the original, while there was one page where white out parts were happening, making renderings very different.

I used **-fuzz 10%** to accept a minor color variation, and used **99 for JPG quality** in my tool so JPEG compression doesn't generate too much differences. Beware on this one, as a *low quality on jpg compression forces you to augment the fuzz factor*, with the risk of missing major visual differences. Unfortunately, you won't find the information in the JPG headers.

I have made my images mid-res (150 dpi), because lo-res proved similar to low JPG quality and generated too much differences. The renderings are same resolution (549*819 = 449 631 pixels), the compare tool is not really strong at finding part of an image in another image. (You'd better off with OpenCV for this.)

Here is a table with some significant results on three different pages in my tool, and then my interpretation of each metric.

[image: All ImageMagick results on identical and different images same resolution and jpeg quality]

The AE stands for *absolute error count*. This metric roughly gives the  number of pixels considered as different, within the 10% fuzz acceptation that I have used. On nearly identical renderings, this value is typically very low, only 18 or 1400 pixels on a total of 450K, while the very different images show nearly 40K different pixels. I think this metric can be checked against a low percentage of total  pixels, but in my case this is not distinctive enough. Say I have 1% = 4500 pixels, *it could be not neglectable if they happen in only one rectangle*. It could be usefull with a geographical dispersion factor but this is more an OpenCV job.

The MEPP is *Mean Error Per Pixel*. As with all *mean statistics* it's not obvious to interpret, but the results are quite distinctive. Jumping from about 6K for same images to a huge 1.7M on different images. The problem is to decide a limit value. You can see in my table I had a page with 470K on this metric but it was a visually acceptable rendering artifact. *What is an acceptable value, then*? As often with mean values, significancy can prove to be very arbitrary and not always appropriate. The only way to find a reasonnable limit is to make a lot of measures on significant cases, maybe using machine learing.

MSE metric is *mean error squared, average of the channel error squared*. Squared delta values are often more significant in statistics, because they *lower the minor differences and accentuate the major ones*. (Linear regression correlation factor benefits from this mathematical behaviour.) This metric proves very interesting in my case because values are very consistent for similar cases : even on the page with a visual artifact and 450K different pixels, the value stays well below 1, while the page with whited out parts jumps to 9. *This MSE metric is clearly very useable in my case*.

NCC means *normalized cross correlation*. Normalized values are not appropriate in my case, as they make colors closer and *diminish the differences between different cases*. You can see this on values, although identical rendering are remarquably close to 1, different renderings have a value of 0.86 which is not so far from 1.

PAE gives you the *absolute peak difference on color channels* on all pixels, so *it doesn't tell how many pixels* are different. And it doesn't work well for RGB or CMYK as it doesn't tell you which channels are concerned. It's no use in my case.

PHASH is *perceptual hash for the sRGB and HCLp colorspaces*. I'm not really sure about this one but the result are very interesting as my images are RGB, and mostly because the values on similar rendering are well below 1  even for the page with acceptable visual artifact - while the different renderings give a value of 26. This is very appropriate for my case, just as MSE. I consider this metric as it seems to even more accentuate the differences between minor and major gaps in color values.

PSNR is *peak signal to noise ratio* : as for PAE, this is a peak value which *won't tell how many pixels are concerned* so it is absolutely unseable in my case.

RMSE is for *root mean squared*. Whatever that means, you find the same squared means behaviour as with MSE, so this value can be interesting as it reveals major differences more than minor ones. Here my values are 0.7 and 3.2 for identical images and a hefty 48.7 for different ones. The difficulty is to decide for an acceptable limit: as with AE or MEPP, the only way is to conduct a lot of tests and measure values for a lot of cases and decide for an appropriate value. Machine learning could help for this.

As a conclusion, I decided to use the PHASH metric. But the very conclusion of this study is that **you must conduct tests and measure them** before deciding the metric to use, as comparison contextes can be very different and metrics can show very different behaviours.

OpenCV is way more appropriate if you have to compare images from different sources, or parts of a global image, or images with big lighting variations. Also, it's quite easy to use from Python and C++. **ImageMagick is quite good in my case because I am the one who generates both images**.

Answer (score 2):

The fuzz factor in **ImageMagick** allows two pixels to be compared and considered as the same although their colours may differ slightly.

The trick to understanding it, is to consider an RGB colour cube with Red, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and Black and White as the vertices. A fuzz factor of 100% represents the greatest possible distance in that cube, i.e. the length of the diagonal from Black to White and everything is scaled relative to that. It is shown dotted in this diagram.

[image]

In general, I would recommend using a percentage value rather than an absolute value, because an absolute fuzz factor of 255 means all colours are the same (black=white) on an 8-bit image, whereas on a 16-bit image, it would be hard to even perceive two colours that differ by 255.

As an example, let's see if a single black pixel is the same as a single mid-grey pixel with 49% fuzz:

```
compare -metric ae -fuzz 49% xc:black xc:gray null:
1
```

No, it is different, there is one pixel difference. Now let's try again allowing the pixels to be 51% different yet still match:

```
compare -metric ae -fuzz 51% xc:black xc:gray null:
0
```

Now they are considered the same.

Comment: I couldn't find any direct research paper published by ImageMagick developers about the algorithms used in ImageMagick. Do u have any idea or a link from where i can find a direct research paper about algorithms used in ImageMagick?

Comment: There is no algorithm as such. Each pixel in the first image is compared, with the specified fuzz, against the same pixel in the second image - the `-metric ae` will tell you the number of pixels that differ, other metrics such as `RMSE` are also available.

Comment: Other metrics can be found at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#statistics. The imagemagick compare does will be sensitive to rotation and scale for all metrics including fuzz. It just searches the offsets in x and y for the best match and does not search rotations or scale changes.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was trying, and clearly failing, to say @fmw42 There is no allowance for scaling or rotation - `pixel[x,y]` in the first image is compared with the corresponding `pixel[x,y]` in the second image. There is no *"allowance"* for scaling or rotation - just for colour variation via fuzz.

Comment: @fmw42 By the way, you may like to apply your considerable knowledge and experience to this question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/43293915/2836621